# Why Does Grails See A Many-to-Many Association Where it Should See a One-to-Many?

Tags: grails, model, associations, grails-orm

I'm working with the following environment:
- Grails 3.0.3, Groovy 2.4.3, JVM 1.8.0.31 ... all running on OSX 10.10.4

After tracing through with a debugger, Grails appears to be seeing the *one-to-many* self association *(parent --> children)* as a *many-to-many*. The result is that when one tries to remove an object from the *children*, grails tries to clean up the other end of the association by calling a remove() method on something that is, of course, not a collection. Not finding an applicable remove() method causes Grails to throw a MissingMethodException... I've isolated the case down to a two level inheritance model where the *abstract* base class defines the parent/children self association. NOTE, the problem does not occur if I collapse the two classes into a single *instantiable* class. Here is the domain model:

```
// CLASS 1 - Abstract Base Class
package com.sandbox

abstract class AbstractBaseClass {

    static hasMany = [ children: AbstractBaseClass ]

    static belongsTo = [ parent: AbstractBaseClass ]

    static constraints = {
    }
}

// CLASS 2 - Instantiable Sub Class
package com.sandbox

class IllustrationCase extends AbstractBaseClass {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Then, my test case where the exception occurs is as follows:

```
package com.sandbox

import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
class IllustrationCaseSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "Deleting Nodes From a Hierarchy"() {
        given:
        // Create the various nodes
        def theParent = new IllustrationCase(
            name: "Parent Node"
        )
        def theChild1 = new IllustrationCase(
            name: "Child Node 1"
        )
        def theChild2 = new IllustrationCase(
            name: "Child Node 2"
        )
        def theChild3 = new IllustrationCase(
            name: "Child Node 3"
        )

        // Create the hierarchy structure
        theParent.addToChildren(
            theChild1
        ).addToChildren(
            theChild2
        ).addToChildren(
            theChild3
        )

        // Perform a DEEP save
        theParent.save( failOnError: true )

        // Remove a child --- This is where the error occurs...
        IllustrationCase.get( theParent.id ).removeFromChildren( IllustrationCase.get( theChild2.id ) )


        expect:

        // Find the parent nodes...
        def targetNode = IllustrationCase.findByName( "Parent Node" )

        targetNode.children.size() == 2
        !targetNode.children.find { it.name == "Child Node 2" }

        targetNode.children.find { it.name == "Child Node 1" }
        targetNode.children.find { it.name == "Child Node 3" }
    }
}
```

Executing the above test case results in the following exception being thrown...

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sandbox.IllustrationCase.remove() is applicable for argument types: (com.sandbox.IllustrationCase) values: [com.sandbox.IllustrationCase : 1]
Possible solutions: merge(com.sandbox.IllustrationCase), merge(), merge(), create(), delete(), save()
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormEnhancer.addRelationshipManagementMethods_closure5(AbstractHibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:183)
    at com.sandbox.IllustrationCaseSpec.$tt__$spock_feature_0_0(IllustrationCaseSpec.groovy:46)
    at com.sandbox.IllustrationCaseSpec.Deleting Nodes From a Hierarchy_closure1(IllustrationCaseSpec.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$1.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:67)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.executeAndRollback(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:64)
    at com.sandbox.IllustrationCaseSpec.Deleting Nodes From a Hierarchy(IllustrationCaseSpec.groovy)
```

Considering the error goes away if I collapse the two classes *(i.e., remove the abstract class and inheritance from the equation)* this is really looking like a potential bug in Grails 3 so I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9148) with the Grails team......

Comment: Just as a side note: you can examine the domain class properties to see if Grails is detecting them properly rather than wait for the test to fail and then have to debug into Grails guts: http://blog.deigote.com/2013/07/30/grails-quickly-examine-a-domain-class-associations/ I find this very useful when dealing with problems like yours, since you get some insights (what's the other side of the association named, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on that utility. The results of running it over com.company.common.Topic confirm my findings --> children: [bidirectional:true, circular:true, otherSide.name:parent, owningSide:false, hasOne:false, manyToOne:false, oneToMany:false, manyToMany:true]
parent: [bidirectional:true, circular:true, otherSide.name:children, owningSide:false, hasOne:false, manyToOne:true, oneToMany:false, manyToMany:false] ... Somewhat curious, despite the 'belongsTo', grails doesn't see either side as owning the association...

Comment: Yeah that's weird, I've never seen it. Maybe it's a bug in Grails 3. I'd try to make the class Hierarchy non abstract and remove the inheritance, and see if it still happens - in the past I've had weird results with inheritance and Gorm (never this bad though). You can also try to isolate it to a small project and then open a bug. With a small project that isolates the bug even people like myself could try to help further :-).

Comment: Good suggestion Deigote, I was thinking the same thing. So I refactored my case into a more simplified version (and revamped my original description accordingly). The issue seems go away if I collapse the class structure into a single class (i.e., take the abstract be class out of the picture). As I mentioned in my revamped post, this is really looking like a bug in Grails 3 so I'm going to post a bug report and see what they think. I'll update things here as more information becomes available...

Comment: Cool! If you can post a link to the bug it would be great, I'm actually interested in this one since I have some heavy inheritance in a couple of Grails projects :)

Comment: I opened the bug report and posted the link at the bottom of my original post. Hopefully the Grails team can get to this one fairly quickly...